# Branch prediction. How does it works in fact?

Tags: x86, branch-prediction

> The branch that is guessed to be the most likely is then fetched and
>   speculatively executed. If it is later detected that the guess was
>   wrong then the speculatively executed or partially executed
>   instructions are discarded and the pipeline starts over with the
>   correct branch, incurring a delay.

The citation comes from wikipedia.

Why is it possible to always discard executed instructions? For example, what about a situation where the first instruction in mispredicted taken branch is `syscall 0x60` ( on Linux it is interruption: "Exit program" ). I know that the program won't be exited in case of misprediction but how the CPU is able to discard?

I know that every instruction ( splitted to micro-ops) must be retired to be finished. Maybe it is important for speculative execution?

Comment: The first stages in the instruction pipeline, which do not modify memory or registers, (for example: instruction fetch and decode) can always be performed without any problem about discarding the results.

Answer (score 1):

Speculative execution typically applies to loading registers and branching. These are easily wound back by the CPU using techniques such as [register renaming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86#Current_implementations).

Not all instructions can be reliably rolled back. As you've identifier, things like a `syscall` can't. For example, if you've made a system call to delete a file the CPU isn't going to be able to roll that back! What happens here is that when speculative execution is active certain instruction cause a "stall" in execution whilst the CPU waits to determine the actual outcome of the branch.

Comment: So, the answer is:
Only easily wound back instruction can be speculatively executed. **First** not easily wound back instruction stops speculative execution till outcome of brnach is not known. Right?

Comment: Why wouldn't `syscall` be easily discarded? It's basically a `jmp`, that only changes the instruction pointer register, right? Any sources on this?

Comment: @vidstige - it's not really just a jump, `syscall` is typically a  transition from user space to kernel space, whereas a regular `jmp` isn't.

Comment: @Sean alright, so you have no sources on this, but are just speculating then.

Comment: @vidstige what kind of source are you even looking for? What syscall does is found in [the manual](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html). That it would be hard to speculate past is a consequence of its semantics.